# Prove that G is an abelian group given $a^2b=b=ba^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let **G** be a semigroup such that $\forall a,b \in$ **G**, $a^2b=b=ba^2$.  Prove that G is an abelian group.

My attempt at the problem.

Fix $a_0 \in G$, then for all $b \in G$, $a_0^2b=ba_0^2=b$.  We let $e =a_0^2$  (that is $\forall b \in G$, $eb=be=b$)

Now let $a \in G$, then $a^2e=e$, but we also have from above that $a^2e=a^2$.   Therefore $a^2=e$ for all $a \in G$.  Thus $e$ is the identity element of G.  Furthermore for any $a \in G$, we have $a^{-1}=a$ since $a^2=e$.  Hence G is a group.  To see that G is abelian, let $a,b \in G$.  Consider the following:

$ab =(ba)^2(ab)=(ba)(ba)(ab)=(ba)ba^2b=(ba)beb=(ba)b^2=(ba)e=ba$

Hence G is an abelian group.

Is this okay?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: This proof is good.

Comment: I must be missing something, have you shown if $a \in G$ then $a^{-1} \in G$?

Comment: @FaraadArmwood Since the assumption implies $a^{2}$= e, this implies $a^{-1}$ =a. Since a is in G, so is the inverse. I agree,the proof looks fine-although beginning with a semigroup is kind of a tedious path for all but simple results.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234: I get what you mean. I was having a brain fart.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood When you say $a^2=e\Rightarrow a^{-1}=a$ you are not multiplying the inverse of $a$ both sides. The equality $a^2=e$ means that $a^{-1}=a$, by definition of inverse element.

Comment: @RafaelHolanda: Check the comment above. I realized that. I'm going to sleep, today has been too long obviously.

Comment: @everyone Thank you guys

Comment: Just a suggestion. Split the problem in two. First prove, as you did, that $a^{2} = e$ for all $a \in G$. Then show that if $a^{2} = e$ (or equivalently $a = a^{-1}$) for all $a \in G$, then $G$ is abelian: this goes like $a b = a^{-1} b^{-1} = (b a)^{-1} = b a$ for all $a, b \in G$.

Comment: Did something make you doubt your proof?